# LPOP or delete in redis list

Tags: redis

I have a redis list

```
a, b, c ,d ,e ,f g, h
```

In my callbacks to a function I get the index for element and I want to delete that index.

LPOP and RPOP are not working for me. How can I delete an element based on index and not value in redis?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Redis list is just a double-linked list and it's not supposed to do that. There is a discussion about this [here](http://redis.io/commands/lrem):
"Elements in a list cannot be pointed to by an index because indexes get invalidated when the list changes."

If you need to remove by an index, and the elements are unique, you can do it with LINDEX + LREM.

Supposing you want to remove the index 3:

```
> LINDEX list 3
"d"
> LREM list 1 d
1
```

Another nice solution should be to use a special string to mark the deleted entries and then run the LREM:

```
> LSET list 2 DELETE
OK
> LSET list 4 DELETE
OK
> LREM list 0 DELETE
2
```

Comment: Not ordo 1. So wierd, you can access by index but not remove by index. why? Requires search for value. further you can not say to a list to remove a value starting from a certain index. its either head or tail meaning you can not be sure to be removing the same index.